# Flask app on Apache, CentOs throws mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server

Tags: python, apache, flask, centos, mod-fcgid

I am developing a Flask application on CentOS 6.6 on Apache and Mysql. It is modified from [The Flask Megatutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux-even-on-the-raspberry-pi). I am able to create normally the database, however when I try to access it from my browser I get 500 internal server error and this in the error_log file:

```
content type: text/html



<h1>Hello world!</h1>
[Sun May 03 18:39:53 2015] [error] [client my.ip.add.res] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Sun May 03 18:39:53 2015] [error] [client my.ip.add.res] Premature end of script headers: runp-mysql.fcgi
```

This is after I've edited down the runp-mysql.fcgi file to this:

```
#!flask/bin/python
#encoding=UTF-8
#import os

print "content type: text/html\n\n"
print ""
print "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
```

Running this from the command line completes correctly.

My httpd.conf file ends with this:

```
FcgidIPCDir /tmp
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/apps/my_app/app/static
    Alias /static /home/apps/my_app/app/static
    ScriptAlias / /home/apps/my_app/runp-mysql.fcgi/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why on earth do you have print statements in your `.fcgi` file? The error is a direct consequence of this _"Premature end of script headers"._

Comment: Ok, so this was a couple months ago and I resolved it already (the exact source of the problem was the python module not working under this version of python, I will add this as an answer to help anyone else). As to why I had print statements I read somewhere that the script headers expected are just a content type html header and was just trying to deploy a simple app.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same and a major issue was the permissions on the file. make sure it is executable and not read only.

Also I do not think that the runp-mysql.fcgi is where you want to do your printing. It should be in the views file. This is where you should have the connection to the your mysql database then start the wscgi server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very loose answer based on my actual problem and I am only uploading it in case someone else follows the same tutorial and also has a problem with deployment.
The gist of it is that under the python version I used (2.7) for deployment the flipflop module did not work and I had to use flup instead. For anyone getting the same error - try it, it might work.